# asp.net persisting session variables across sub-domains

Tags: asp.net, subdomain, single-sign-on, forms-authentication, session-variables

I have two ASP.NET applications using Forms Authentication and Single Sign On and I would like to persist Session variables between them.

Upon testing, I cant seem to get the Session variables to be read from the other application. Both apps are on the same domain (app1.domain.com & app2.domain.com) and I have set up my config (a.f.a.i.k.) correctly to reflect this.

I have noticed that when testing on the release server the session id is different even when using tab pages on the same browser (I thought they would be the same!), yet debugging on my local IIS the session id is the same (and I still cant read session variables across sub-domains).

Anyone got any pointers to what I may have missed?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SessionState mode is **InProc** which means Session State data is stored in each AppDomain's memory. AppDomains are isolated, and they do not share SessionState.

You need **SQLServer** or **StateServer** as [SessionState mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx).

Comment: Both applications are in the same domain

Comment: Please do not confuse with AppDomain (application domain) and URL sub domain. Since you have two different web applications, they run on two different AppDomain in IIS.

Comment: OK so to be clear (my understanding of IIS is still a little hazy), I have two web sites running on the same server with the same domain name, but because they are different web sites (not applications within the default web site), they have different AppDomains and thus cannot share Session variables?